# Building a Maven multi module project as single jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

I've developed a simple Maven multi-module project that is fully functional. The goal in this project is to package two jars (from module `a` and module `b`) into a single fully functional jar containing both applications. The project can be launched through either MainA or MainB. Here's the project:
[Maven multi module project](https://github.com/FelipeAumannRS/maven-multi-module)

While the project runs smoothly within the IDE (either running `MainA`, `MainB`, or the final jar), I encounter an issue when attempting to execute the final .jar outside the project directory. Upon running `mvn clean install` in the root project folder, the final jar (possibly referred to as an uber jar, not sure though) is generated in the `a` module's target folder with the name `a-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. However, when I try to run this jar (`java -jar a-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`) outside the IDE, the execution fails.

I suspect that the dependencies are not being properly included in the final jar, despite using the maven-assembly-plugin. I've reviewed my configurations but haven't been able to identify the cause of this issue.

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From a quick look to he project files, it seems you have configured the assembly plugin. There should be a file a-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar under a/target. Is there? If so, try running that with `java -jar`.

Comment: If this project uses Spring Boot as base you should NOT use maven-assembly-plugin. The way to go is via spring-boot-maven-plugin... also use most recent versions of spring boot because the one you are using is end of life (https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support) ...

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos you are correct, it have this jar in there. But it's the other one that works though

Comment: @khmarbaise unfortunately, due to compatibility issues, I'm unable to upgrade to Spring version >3.x. Also, if I can't use maven-assembly-plugin, any thoughts on how can I wrap multiple jars into a single one? (with maven-assembly-plugin works though, I wonder why.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my surprise, it worked with `maven-shade-plugin`!

Just had to remove all plugins from sub-modules, and in the parent module I added it:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>shade-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>login.Main</Main-Class>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And there you have it. Multi module maven project with Spring boot with multiple jars (from different entry Main classes) self-contained in a single jar. Soon I'll be updating the project with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not misunderstood, that you have two modules `a` and `b`, and you want to package `module-b` into `module-a` as single jar that can be directly run.

As you mentioned that `maven-assembly-plugin` is fully functional, try adding this to your `module-a` pom.xml file.

```xml
<plugin>  
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>3.1.0</version>  
    <configuration>  
        <!-- Set jar file name -->
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-all</finalName>  
        <!-- disabled default file name suffix of "jar-with-dependencies" -->
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>  
        <descriptorRefs>  
            <!-- Add all dependency to jar file -->
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>  
        </descriptorRefs>  
        <attach>false</attach>  
        <archive>  
            <manifest>  
                <!-- replace to your main class name -->
                <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass> 
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries> 
            </manifest>   
        </archive>  
    </configuration>  
    <executions>  
        <execution>  
            <!-- Set effect phase -->
            <id>make-assembly</id>  
            <phase>package</phase>  
            <goals>  
                <goal>single</goal>  
            </goals>  
        </execution>  
    </executions>  
</plugin>
```

After `clean install` the `target` directory will generate a `xxx-all.jar` file, and now you can run with `java -jar xxx-all.jar`.

Comment: as mentioned, I already added this plugin to module `a`, but I added your code anyways. same behavior. btw, you could have tried it in less than 5 minutes in the application